# Почему слово троЕчник пишется через Е?

Tags: орфография, существительные, суффиксы

Почему суффикс -ЕЧ, а не -ИЧ в слове троечник.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В прилагательных, образованных от существительных, оканчивающихся на -ка, после мягких согласных, шипящих и ц в безударном положении пишется еч-н. Аналогично с образованными от них существительными:

> - ложка - ложечный - ложечник
> - балалайка - балалаечный - балалаечник
> - тройка - троечный - троечник